# Multiple UIImageViews does not respond to touches.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am working on an application which requires several UIImageViews to be added. 
A modal view controller is presented with different buttons. 
When dismissing the modal view controller it sends tag of the button which helps us deciding which UIImageView to add.

Now when I add first UIImageView, all the gestures work on it. But upon adding the second one, the first one loses response to touch.

The code to add the UIImageView (Body:UIImageView) is :

```
-(void) addBodyToStage:(int)index {
NSString * imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Body%i.png",index];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
Body * body = [[Body alloc] initWithImage:image];

//For Pan Gestures
[body setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[body addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture addTarget:body action:@selector(handlePan:)];

//For Pinch Gestures
[pinchGesture addTarget:body action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
[body addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];


//Adding to the view
[self.view addSubview:body];

}
```

Comment: Add a new instance of the pan gesture for each of the views, or use a single gesture recognizer on their shared superview and use `CGRectContainsPoint` for each of the frames to see to see if the gesture's `locationInView` is contained therein.

Comment: Have you resolved above issue? I am facing same issue...

Answer (score 0):

do you initialize the gesture recognizers anywhere?  It looks like you might be repurposing the same gesture recognizer to different imageViews.  Try instantiating new gesture recognizers for each imageView

Answer (score 0):

The same panGestureRecognizer, and pinchGestureRecognizer (the instance variable) has been added to all the imageViews. There is no problem with that per se, but I think you want different pan/pinch gesture recognizers for each imageView. The view will retain the gesture gesture recognizers so you can add the code in this method itself.

Go

```
  -(void) addBodyToStage:(int)index {
     NSString * imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Body%i.png",index];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageString];
    Body * body = [[Body alloc] initWithImage:image];

   //Alloc the pan/pinch gesture recognizers here
   //remember to alloc/init/autorelease (if not using ARC) 
   //else just alloc init
   //Remove the instantiation of those gesture recognizers in any other 
   //part of the  code.

   //For Pan Gestures
   [body setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
   [body addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
   [panGesture addTarget:body action:@selector(handlePan:)];

   //For Pinch Gestures
   [pinchGesture addTarget:body action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
   [body addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];


   //Adding to the view
   [self.view addSubview:body];

   }
```

Comment: What is Body? Is it subclass or what ?

Comment: Body is a subclass of UIView

Answer (score 0):

Gesture recognizers can only be assigned to one view at a time. If you assign them to another view, they are implicitly unassigned from the first. You will need to initialize gesture recognizers for every view, or place the gesture recognizer on a view lower in the hierarchy and use the `view` property of the gesture recognizer to tell which one was touched.